# Redis multi/exec with an evented driver

Tags: ruby, redis, eventmachine

How do you use `MULTI`/`EXEC` (and `WATCH`) in an evented Redis driver like the `em-hiredis` (a Ruby driver that use EventMachine)? If I run:

```
redis.multi do
  redis.sadd("foo", "bar") do
    redis.inc("baz", "qux") do
      redis.exec do
        puts 'yay!'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

there's a chance that some other part of the application manages to sneak in an operation before the `EXEC`, if there is a lot going on (imagine, for example, that I have a timer that increments some key every second, and that the code above takes more than one second to run, then some of the increment commands will be sent as part of the `MULTI`/`EXEC` -- what if I want to abort the transaction? Then any increments that happened to become part of it will disappear. It's easy to come up with even worse scenarios).

I guess I could implement some kind of locking so that no other actions can be done while a `MULTI`/`EXEC` is in progress, but that doesn't feel like a great solution, has anyone else found a better way?

Comment: did you have a look at https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony it has an handler for em-hiredis

Comment: Yes I know about `em-synchrony`, but it doesn't change anything. Things will still happen in the same order, it will just be easier to see the flow of control (but in this case I would say that it would also make the race condition less obvious).

Comment: For this kind of thing to work you got to open a seperate connection or use a connection pool.

Comment: Oh btw: You could also go with the new redis `scripting` branch which allows you to send LUA scripts as commands.

Comment: @balu it's my analysis of the problem too, this can't be done in an async environment with only one connection. I'm still hoping someone has an elegant solution though. Otherwise I guess it can be implemented by implementing a basic connection pool.

Comment: I talked to some devs in #redis a while ago and they confirmed it. IMHO a connection pool is a pretty good thing to use here. :)

Comment: could you rewrite your comments as an answer? if it's so, then that would be my accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @balu stated in the comments to the question it cannot be done without multiple connections.

Comment: If someone would write a proper answer to this question I will gladly make it the accepted answer, and delete this one.

Comment: hi, can you answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457538/sql-trigger-after-insert-update-another-table-with-conditions), thank you